# Python list within a class slice is not working

Tags: python, list, slice

I have been working with Python in the past, set it aside and now I am happy to be back. I am trying to access the first two elements in a list but I keep getting just the first element, and not the second.

The following is from the Python shell. It seems that when I use `[i:j]` when `j=i+1`, I am getting just the first element. Is this the correct behavior?

```
>>> p=['ho','he','hoo']
>>> p
['ho', 'he', 'hoo']
>>> p[0:1]
['ho']
>>> p[1:0]
[]
>>> p[0:1]
['ho']
>>> p[1]
'he'
>>> p[0:3]
['ho', 'he', 'hoo']
>>> p[0:2]
['ho', 'he']
 >>> p[0:3]
['ho', 'he', 'hoo']
>>> p[1:2]
['he']
```

The Python version I use is:

> Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 21 2011, 21:11:06) 
>   [GCC 4.6.0 20110212 (Red Hat 4.6.0-0.7)] on linux2

The Linux is Centos, kernel is

> Linux Fedora 2.6.41.4-1.fc15.x86_64 #1

Comment: "Is this the correct behavior?"  Yes.  What confuses you about that?  Could you start your assumptions or your reasoning behind thinking it might be wrong?

Comment: You ought to brush up on the slicing syntax.  Slices include the start from index, but exclude the to index.  So `myList[0:2]` gets positions 0 and 1.  If you're starting with 0 you can omit it, so `myList[:2]` is analogous.

Comment: Slicing in Python is the first item you want, followed by the first item you *don't* want.

Answer (score 7):

In the `p[i:j]`, `j` is non inclusive: you'll select all the elements from `i` to `j - 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Python slices use a inclusive beginning index and exclusive ending index. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) for more details. So:

```
>>> list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> i = 2
>>> j = 3
>>> # remember that lists are zero based
>>> print list[i:j] # includes 2 and up to, but not 3
[2]
>>> print list[i:j+1] # includes 2 and up to, but not 3+1
[2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the correct behavior. From the [`docs`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

> The slice of s from i to j is defined as the sequence of items with
>   index k such that i <= k < j.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the correct behavior. [i:i+1] will give you one item. [i:i+5] will give you five. That's intentional, and the reason is just the obvious clarity you get with this, as you can quickly see how many items you get without further thinking about it.

Comment: Thanks. I am a PERL and SKILL scripter by origin. It does not work like this in these languages.

Comment: I know. Yet another detail where Python kicks other languages ass.